# Regex: parsing scripts in c#

Tags: c#, regex, scripting

I'm currently writing a script editing app in c# to edit game scripts. I want to be able to load a script file and get the name of an NPC object and the script contents. The script looks like this:

```
INSTANCE PC_Thief(NPC_DEFAULT)

{
    //-------- primary data --------
    name            = "Diego";
    Npctype         = NPCTYPE_FRIEND;
    guild           = GIL_STT;
    level           = 999;          // real 25, aber 999 damit er nicht vor dem Troll flieht!
    voice           = 11;
    id              = 1;
    flags           = NPC_FLAG_IMMORTAL;

    //-------- visuals --------
    //                      animations
    Mdl_SetVisual       (self,"HUMANS.MDS");
    //                          Body-Mesh           Body-Tex    Skin-Color  Head-MMS                Head-Tex    Teeth-Tex
    Mdl_SetVisualBody (self,"hum_body_Naked0",      0,          2,          "Hum_Head_Thief",   15,         4,  STT_ARMOR_H);


    //--------- abilities --------
    attribute[ATR_STRENGTH]     =   70;
    attribute[ATR_DEXTERITY]    =   90;
    attribute[ATR_MANA_MAX]     =   0;
    attribute[ATR_MANA]         =   0;
    attribute[ATR_HITPOINTS_MAX]=   340;
    attribute[ATR_HITPOINTS]    =   340;

    protection[PROT_FIRE]       =   1000;

    Npc_SetTalentSkill  (self, NPC_TALENT_PICKPOCKET,1);Npc_SetTalentValue(self,NPC_TALENT_PICKPOCKET,60); 
    Npc_SetTalentSkill  (self, NPC_TALENT_SNEAK,    1); 
    Npc_SetTalentSkill  (self, NPC_TALENT_PICKLOCK, 1);Npc_SetTalentValue(self,NPC_TALENT_PICKLOCK,60); 
    Npc_SetTalentSkill  (self, NPC_TALENT_MAGE,     6);

    Npc_SetTalentSkill  (self, NPC_TALENT_1H,1);
    Npc_SetTalentSkill  (self, NPC_TALENT_BOW,1);

    //-------- inventory --------
    EquipItem           (self, Diegos_Bogen);
    EquipItem           (self, ItMw_1H_Sword_04);
    CreateInvItems      (self, ItAmArrow, 100);

    //-------- ai --------
    daily_routine               = Rtn_PreStart_1;
    fight_tactic                = FAI_HUMAN_MASTER;
    self.aivar[AIV_IMPORTANT]   = TRUE;
    senses                      = SENSE_SEE|SENSE_HEAR|SENSE_SMELL;
};
```

and here is the regex I'm using:

```
Regex ireg = new Regex("(instance|prototype)\\s+(?<ins>[^\\s]+).*\\{(?<text>[^(\\};)]+)\\};", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

However when I run this Rgex, I get the  group, but all the  group contains is 2 newlines.
What am I doing wrong? I set the regex to singleline mode so that . would also match \n. Is that a wrong way of doing this? Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Next time you ask a question please be more detailed in specifying what you want. You did not even mention what is that you wanted to have as the output of the two capture groups. Better questions get better answers. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read your comments and i think this regex should do the trick

```
(instance|prototype)\\s+(?<ins>[^\\s(]+)[^{]*{(?<text>[^}]+)};
```

Note: I have already escaped characters as required for .net.

I recommend that you use the regex this way instead of using escape character for .net, this is much cleaner to read

```
@"(instance|prototype)\s+(?<ins>[^\s(]+)[^{]*{(?<text>[^}]+)};"
```

The capture group
'ins' will contain "PC_Thief"
and 'text' will contain the entire input between { and  }

Answer (score 0):

Not even sure what your regex is supposed to do, but this one should work:

```
"name\s*=\s*\"([^\"]*)\"\s*;"
```

The [^\"] part matches anything but a ".  If the game script allows " inside names using some escaping mechanism, you'd have to modify the regex.

Here is a [good place to test regular expressions](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx).

Comment: My regex is meant to capture 1. the INSTANCE name eg PC_Thief and 2. the whole text of the script, without the { and };
Then that script is passed to another function which actually parses the script.

Comment: Also sorry, I just noticed that my &gt; and &lt; tags were eaten in the first post - the &lt;ins&gt; group captures correctly, but the &lt;text&gt; group only contains 2 newlines.

Comment: After testing a bit on the site you posted, i noticed that the regex has trouble matching the }; needed to end the script. Does the ; have to be escaped? Even if I try to just match the }, the regex matches nothing. How do I match the } properly?

Comment: Right, you wanted the name, I see Jass got it right already.  The } is a special character, you can escape it like \}.  It's used to specify the amount of repetition, f.e. a{1,3} would match between one and three a's.